# replacing for loop to map method

Tags: swift, for-loop, methods

I am stuck about this goal.

> Learn about the `map` method, and use it in place of the loop that converts the array of characters to an array of strings in `updateUI()`.

I have read Documentation and topics about `map`, but still all my tries did not work.

```
//change loop below to map method

for letter in currentGame.formattedWord {
    letters.append(String(letter))
}
let wordWithSpacing = letters.joined(separator: " ")      
correctWordLabel.text = wordWithSpacing
scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses: \(totalLosses)"
treeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show us your most promising attempt at using `map()` and explain how it fails?

Answer (score 3):

The `String` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) tells us:

> A string is a series of characters, such as "Swift", that forms a collection.

So, you can use `map` to convert each of these characters to individual strings:

```
let string = "Hello, world"

let letters = string.map { (character: Character) -> String in
    return String(character)
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
let letters = string.map { String($0) }
```

Comment: i was about to write answer when i see yours (Y)

Comment: Or `let letters = string.map(String.init)` maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I did it. the problem was that I left the var letters as an empty array and tried to add characters to this array. Now I realized that this was wrong.

```
func updateUI() {
            let letters = currentGame.formattedWord
            let mappedLetters = letters.map { String($0)} 

       /* for letter in currentGame.formattedWord {
           letters.append(String(letter))
            } */
```

Thanks all!